# Change Google Maps v3 mapOptions object after load

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How can i modify a V3 map's mapOptions (after the initial map has been loaded)?

Specifically, I would like to be able to flip the

```
draggable: false
```

option to

```
draggable: true
```

When an action (such as a click on a div) is triggered.

Addition: I have tried loading jquery-ui-map and using:

```
$('#map').gmap('option', 'draggable', true);
```

However this seems to reload the map and forget all the other existing options. I could redefine them all, but that seems a bit hackish.

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I was going to say, why on Earth complicate things with jQuery when it's easy enough to do it directly?....glad you already found out. :-)

Comment: Please answer your own question to close it.

Comment: any idea why this doesn't work to update the controls? ie map.set(scaleControl, false);

Comment: pretend I was never here, 'true' = string (hangs head in shame)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Found that I don't even need jQuery for this – it's already part of the Google Maps API. Simply do:

```
map.set('draggable', true);
```

Too easy! Hope it helps someone.

======
2020 update - you should use:

```
map.setOptions({ draggable: true });
```

Comment: 2020 update: you should use `map.setOptions({ draggable: false });` these days.

Answer (score 11):

**Google Maps JavaScript API V3.25 update**

Note that `map.set()` does not work in newer versions of Maps API. You have to use `map.setOptions()`

Source: [Google Maps Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

Comment: Good point. Quick syntax usage for those unfamiliar: map.setOptions({gestureHandling: 'greedy'});

Answer (score 4):

If you have already created the map previously, you can set several options ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions ) at once like this:

```
var myOptions = {
                    zoom:11,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    panControl: false
                };

map.set(myOptions);
```

Comment: This kind of worked for me, but my map object doesn't have a `set()` function, so I had to use `setOptions(myOptions)`, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Unixmonkey Thanks =)

Comment: Note that you don't need to set every single option.  That is, omitting previously set options won't revert them to their default - you only need to set what you'd like to change.  E.g. `map.setOptions({ draggable : true })`.