# How to move inside google maps only with two fingers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3, user-experience

I have a big problem for mobile users:

i have a google maps that has `width: 100%` and so when the user scroll the window if touch the screen "inside" the map, the scroll it will be only for map and not for all window... (yesterday my father for 3 minutes scrolled inside the map XD)

To scroll the window is possible touch the border of screen, but is very very scrict and not all users understand this. 
I dont'want a map with a `width` less of `100%` so i must found other solution...

This is it will be make the map draggable only when it is touch with **two fingers**, almost when pinch to zoom...

but which google maps event i can to use ?

maybe:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(event){
      this.setOptions({draggable:true});
    });
```

but maybe at first click on map i should to alert (with a div in map) that is possible to move the map with two fingers ??

What do you think? and code is correct?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english and for strange question :D

Comment: **why downvote me** ?

Comment: This is very usefull for mobile scrolling. I notice today that *Google has added a native block for one finger move*, now, at least when using the API, u can only move the map with two fingers. e.g.: http://cmwautomacao.com.br/contato.php

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using API v3.27 or higher. While initializing map just add property `gestureHandling: 'Cooperative'`

like this

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng,
          gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
        });
```

[More Info Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction)

Or if you want to do this after creating the map, do

```
map.setOptions({gestureHandling: 'cooperative'});
```

[More Info Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072116/change-google-maps-v3-mapoptions-object-after-load)

Comment: What about an embedded map using iFrame tag on a web view app?

Answer (score 3):

Although this is quite strange requirement, you can try the following;

```js
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    if(e.touches.length == 2){
      //This means there are two finger move gesture on screen
      googleMapsReference.setOptions({draggable:true});
    }
}, false);
```

I have not tested this on a mobile device but it should give you a starting point.

Comment: hmm maybe is better than use google maps event.... when i will try your code (2-3 days) i will tell you if is work... thanks a lot for good idea and help.  Now i wait other helps :D

Comment: why you add "e.preventDefault" ?

Comment: Depending on the usage, you can remove it. It is there to prevent the default action of the event. You can refer to https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ for details.

Comment: What about an embedded map using iFrame tag on a web view app?

Comment: Instead of using document selector, you may try to target the iframe and grab its document object to add the listener